# Oracle PreparedStatement / Parameter error

Tags: c#, oracle

Using this code I am able to get data from Oracle database.

```
 public static ArrayList CheckIfPrinterExists()
        {
            string printerName = @"PRINTER1234";
            ArrayList colValues = new ArrayList();
            try
            {

                string constr = @"DATA SOURCE=someSource;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=root;password=root";
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"select * from print_spooler where spoolername = 'Printer1234'";
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    colValues.Add(reader["id"] + ";" + reader["id2"] + ";" + reader["id3"]);
                }
                con.Dispose();
                reader.Dispose();
                return colValues;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I tried modifiying the code using prepared statement which is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static ArrayList CheckIfPrinterExists()
        {
            string printerName = @"printer1234";
            ArrayList colValues = new ArrayList();
            try
            {

                string constr = @"DATA SOURCE=someSource;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=root;password=root";
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"select * from print_spooler where spoolername = @ParamPrinterName";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@ParamPrinterName", printerName));
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    colValues.Add(reader["id"] + ";" + reader["id2"] + ";" + reader["id3"]);
                }
                con.Dispose();
                reader.Dispose();
                return colValues;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Here is a better view on the changes (If I am correct the 2nd not working optin is better to use because of SQL injection).

[image]

Comment: `select * from print_spooler where spoolername = :ParamPrinterName`; Oracle uses `:` not `@` as binding variable prefix

Comment: @DmitryBychenko wow, that did the job! thanks, good to know!

Comment: Side note: let *obsolete* `ArrayList` rest in peace. `List<String>`

Comment: Side note: do not `Dispose` *explicitly*, but wrap into `using`: `OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr) {...}`

Comment: Side note: `select id1, id2, id3 ... ` is a better choice than `select * `: do you really want *all* columns to be fetched when you read just `3` of them

Comment: Side note: catching *all* exceptions - `catch (Exception ex)` - is a *bad practice*; `catch (DataException ex)`